# "set varsize-limit x" returns "No current definition of "varsize" in current context."

Tags: gdb, ada, gnat

I'm using gdb in the command line to debug some really old stuff in Ada. When I try to print a part of a really large record, I get the message "record type with dynamic size is larger than varsize-limit." Naturally, I try to change this with `set`, but I get the error from title; `show` returns the same message. The `set` command works in GVD or the GDB with the graphic interface.

Comment: make sure you're using the gdb provided with the GNAT install, i.e. put the bin directory of GNAT in your PATH

Comment: NB: it's Ada, not ADA (the American Dental Association).

Comment: Maybe you’re using an ancient GDB? (`show varsize-limit` works in gdb 7.7)